# Связать checkbox c текстом

Tags: javascript, jquery

Появилась одна проблемка. Связать то текст с `checkbox` я могу, но с одним кодом который я нашел и вроде более менее разобрался, отредактировал  чуть-чуть под себя - не выходит. Нужно это для того, что-бы можно было удалить\добавить ветку. То есть через `checkbox` выделить и потом уже как-то взаимодействовать. Я думал что лучшим вариантом будет добавить в объект еще одно свойство, типа `id` c которым нужно связаться. Удобнее всего было бы конечно же использовать цифры, но они уже есть... Помогите пожалуйста! Вроде бы и есть мысль, но никак "додумать" не могу.

```js
var listCategories = {
  data: [

    {
      itemId: 1,
      itemName: "пункт №1",
      itemParentId: 0
    },

    {
      itemId: 2,
      itemName: "пункт №1.1",
      itemParentId: 1
    },

    {
      itemId: 3,
      itemName: "пункт №1.2",
      itemParentId: 1
    },

    {
      itemId: 4,
      itemName: "пункт №2",
      itemParentId: 0
    },

    {
      itemId: 5,
      itemName: "пункт №3",
      itemParentId: 0
    },

    {
      itemId: 6,
      itemName: "пункт №3.1",
      itemParentId: 5
    },

    {
      itemId: 7,
      itemName: "пункт №3.2",
      itemParentId: 5
    },

    {
      itemId: 8,
      itemName: "пункт №3.3",
      itemParentId: 5
    },

    {
      itemId: 9,
      itemName: "пункт №4",
      itemParentId: 0
    },

    {
      itemId: 10,
      itemName: "пункт №5",
      itemParentId: 0
    },

    {
      itemId: 11,
      itemName: "пункт №5.1",
      itemParentId: 10
    }

  ]
};

function createTree(data, parentId) {

  parentId = parentId || 0;
  var items = data.filter(function(el) {
    return el.itemParentId == parentId;
  });
  if (items.length == 0) return null;

  var tree = $('<ul>').addClass('tree');
  tree.append(
    items.map(
      function(el) {

        var li = $('<li>').append(
            $('<input type="checkbox">')
          ).append(
            $('<a>').addClass('state')
          ).append(
            $('<label>').html(el.itemName).attr('id', el.itemId).addClass('item')
          ),
          nestedTree = createTree(data, el.itemId);
        if (nestedTree !== null) {
          li.append(nestedTree)
            .addClass('collapse');
        }
        return li;
      }
    )
  );
  return tree;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  var tree = createTree(listCategories.data);

  $('#tree').append(tree)
            .on('dblclick', '.item',function(){
                $(this).attr("contenteditable", "true");
            })

            .on('click', '.item',function(){
                $('.active').not(this).removeClass('active');
                $(this).toggleClass('active');
            })

            .on('click', '.state',function(){
                $(this).parent().toggleClass('collapse expand');
            })

});
```

```css
ul.tree {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
}
.active {
  background-color: orange;
}
.state {
  position: absolute;
  left: 1em;
}
.collapse > .state::after {
  content: '+';
}
.expand > .state::after {
  content: '-';
}
.collapse > ul {
  display: none;
}
.expand > ul {
  display: block;
}
.item {
  cursor: pointer;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tree"></div>
```

Comment: объясните что Вы хотите сделать? Только больше конкретики и меньше своего объяснений что у Вас не получилось и почему, это отвлекает :)

Comment: @OlmerDale Нужно связать текст с checkbox для выделения ветки -  что бы можно было ее  удалить или же добавить новую. Текст в label уже "обернул", осталось каким-то образом дописать id у checkbox и добавить атрибут for в этот самый label

Comment: Вам нужно по нажатию на `пункт №...` сделать активным чекбокс?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может быть так:

```js
var listCategories = {
  data: [

    {
      itemId: 1,
      itemName: "пункт №1",
      itemParentId: 0
    },

    {
      itemId: 2,
      itemName: "пункт №1.1",
      itemParentId: 1
    },

    {
      itemId: 3,
      itemName: "пункт №1.2",
      itemParentId: 1
    },

    {
      itemId: 4,
      itemName: "пункт №2",
      itemParentId: 0
    },

    {
      itemId: 5,
      itemName: "пункт №3",
      itemParentId: 0
    },

    {
      itemId: 6,
      itemName: "пункт №3.1",
      itemParentId: 5
    },

    {
      itemId: 7,
      itemName: "пункт №3.2",
      itemParentId: 5
    },

    {
      itemId: 8,
      itemName: "пункт №3.3",
      itemParentId: 5
    },

    {
      itemId: 9,
      itemName: "пункт №4",
      itemParentId: 0
    },

    {
      itemId: 10,
      itemName: "пункт №5",
      itemParentId: 0
    },

    {
      itemId: 11,
      itemName: "пункт №5.1",
      itemParentId: 10
    }

  ]
};

function createTree(data, parentId) {

  parentId = parentId || 0;
  var items = data.filter(function(el) {
    return el.itemParentId == parentId;
  });
  if (items.length == 0) return null;

  var tree = $('<ul>').addClass('tree');
  tree.append(
    items.map(
      function(el) {

        var li = $('<li>').append(
            $('<input type="checkbox">').attr('id', el.itemId)
          ).append(
            $('<a>').addClass('state')
          ).append(
            $('<label>').html(el.itemName).attr('for', el.itemId).addClass('item')
          ),
          nestedTree = createTree(data, el.itemId);
        if (nestedTree !== null) {
          li.append(nestedTree)
            .addClass('collapse');
        }
        return li;
      }
    )
  );
  return tree;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  var tree = createTree(listCategories.data);

  $('#tree').append(tree)
            .on('dblclick', '.item',function(){
                $(this).attr("contenteditable", "true");
            })

            .on('click', '.item',function(){
                $('.active').not(this).removeClass('active');
                $(this).toggleClass('active');
            })

            .on('click', '.state',function(){
                $(this).parent().toggleClass('collapse expand');
            })

});
```

```css
ul.tree {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
}
.active {
  background-color: orange;
}
.state {
  position: absolute;
  left: 1em;
}
.collapse > .state::after {
  content: '+';
}
.expand > .state::after {
  content: '-';
}
.collapse > ul {
  display: none;
}
.expand > ul {
  display: block;
}
.item {
  cursor: pointer;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tree"></div>
```

*Связь `<input type="checkbox" id="InputID">` с `<label for="InputId">` происходит по `id` и `for`.*

Comment: Благодарю! :) А вот еще вопрос, как можно было бы вывести на экран текст который находится внутри label? Решил попробовать, а не получилось.

Comment: @Mark_8, простите не поняла. Там же и находятся пункт №1 ...

Comment: Прошу прощения, спросил глупость. Не берите в голову :)